# Kendo Grid command.custom url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am trying to get command.custom to work with a url.  i have `command.Custom("Tasks");` and it creates the button like it should.  But i can't figure out how to get it to point to this url `../../OBClientSetupTasks/Index/@item.SetupID`

I tried to make it do a .action and click through the controller and view but it returns a not supported exception

```
 command.Custom("Tasks").Action("Index", "OBClientSetup");
```

I also can't seem to identify `@item.SetupID` . item is usually from a foreach, but in this case I don't see where a foreach would go.

EDIT:

Adding full grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<XXX_2_0_OBOE.OpenAccess.OBClientSetup>()
          .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.ProfileName);
              columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.Default).ClientTemplate("#= Default ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
              columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.EEFinalize).ClientTemplate("#= EEFinalize ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
              columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.AllowOutsideCodes).ClientTemplate("#= EEFinalize ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
              columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.Completed).ClientTemplate("#= Completed ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
              columns.Command(command =>
              {
                  command.Custom("Tasks").Action("Index", "OBClientSetup", new { SetupID = Model.SetupID });
                  command.Edit();
                  command.Destroy().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "onboard-delete " });
              });
          })
          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
          {
              toolbar.Template(@<text>
                <div class="toolbar">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='FieldFilter' placeholder="Search Profile Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </text>);
          })
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table-responsive" })
                  .Groupable()
                  .Pageable()
                  .Sortable()
                  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()
                      .Read(read => read.Action("OB2_ClientProfiles", "OB"))
                      .PageSize(5)
                      .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "OB"))
                      .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "OB"))
                      .Model(model => model.Id(obcs => obcs.SetupID))
                  )
    )
```

The Model

```
public partial class OBClientSetup
{
    private int _setupID;
    public virtual int SetupID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._setupID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._setupID = value;
        }
    }
```

The idea is so they can click a button and be sent to `OBClientSetupTasks/Index/1` or whatever their ID is

Comment: Please post your view and controller action. And what's this @item? Do you mean @Model.SetupID?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Grid's model that way you'll probably need something like this:

Create a JavaScript function to handle the click event. Here you can grab the SetupID. I don't know what you're controller's action is going, but there are a few options.

If you want to change to the Index page, do something like this:

```
<script>
    function SetupTasks(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "OBClientSetup")' + "/" + dataItem.SetupID;
    }
</script>
```

Or, execute some ajax request like this:

```
<script>
    function SetupTasks(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        windows.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "OBClientSetup")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { SetupID: dataItem.SetupID },
            success: function (data) {
                // Handle return value
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In your grid specify your command button like this:

```
command.Custom("Tasks").Click("SetupTasks");
```

Comment: For some reason it says `System.Collections.Generic.List<XXX_2_0_OBOE.OpenAccess.OBClientSetup>' does not contain a definition for 'SetupID'` but it's in the model